# Match java date with simpledateformat

Tags: java, parsing, date

I'm busy parsing the following date:
Tue Jun 19 10:06:19 2012

I use http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html for this. With the following format: EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy

I would say this is alright, even when I take a look at the manual, but I keep getting exceptions with as message: Unabled to parse date Unparseable date: "Tue Jun 19 10:06:19 2012"

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution, it had something to do with the locale (which was not set), this works just fine:

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Comment: I also ran into this, as you say, it is incorrect locale. Some locale is always set and if you have specific date format, you should always use the SimpleDateFormat constructor with additional Locale parameter.